# LoadfromText gives error 2285 (Microsoft Office Access can't create the output file)

Tags: ms-access, vba

When importing forms in access using loadfromtext, I continually get a runtime error 2285. Searching the internet shows many people with the same problem, yet no solutions. Does anyone know what causes this bug?

**Edit:**
In addition a file called 'errors.txt' is created in the folder containing the database.

**Edit: Sort of solution:**
I never got around to asking my system operator about the hotfixes, but the function did work as expected at home. I logged in this morning and it works here to (no changes to ms access in the mean time). I'm guessing this is an internal bug in ms access, not in the vba code.

If you experience the same error, try a cold reboot, wait a while and hopefully you the problem goes away. If you could list the specific circumstances under which the error occured maybe the bug can eventually be found.

Finally in related news: At http://www.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0045.htm an access addin can be found to export your forms/tables. This one has been verfied to work, so you can check if the problem is in your own code or some access bug.

P.S. Thanks Remou for your patience and help. I've upvoted the hotfix answer because it seems to be closest to the eventual solution.

---

My version is Office Access 2003(11.8166.8221) SP3

---

Yep I'm using a new database. I'm trying to set up a system where you have all form definitions as text files so that they can be version controlled, and that there is a clean database that is 'compiled' based on these text representations.

the code I'm using is a basic

```
Application.LoadFromText acForms, left(filename, len(filename)-len(".frm.txt")), filename
```

I have checked (by stepping through the code using F8) that the formname is correct and the filename is correct and including the drivename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is related to errors occuring for users of the Access Source Code Control Integration.

The solution can be found here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927680
"This issue occurs if the Access default file type differs from the file type for the Access database that is in the Visual SourceSafe project."

In other words:
The default file type found in "Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Default file format" is different from the file format of the database you are using LoadFromText on, or from the database you used SaveAsText on. The file format of the database can be found in the Access title bar.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I found I could resolve it by making sure that all the Access objects had unique names.

Access allows you to have the same name for a Report as the name you gave to a Query or Form.  I liked the idea of this as I then knew which queries lay behind which forms and reports and which reports were paper copies of what was shown by the forms.

Giving these the same names however produced my 2285 error.  When I gave a unique name, the problem went away.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with SP3, have you applied the hotfix?

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/945674

Answer (score 0):

Well i solved putting in a textbox the value of the file to be imported, and calling that textbox in the field "Textfile" of the command:

Me!textbox = "C:\temp\" & nameofiletobeimported

Application.LoadFromText acForm, nameofform, Me!textbox

Infact, for some reasons i don't know, the value in textbox, correctly solved, was not directly solved by the command.... by my opinion it's a bug of that function