# Splitting MS Access Database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am working on a database with one other person. We have successfully split the database into a frontend and a backend, where the frontend contains the queries, reports, and forms, and is linked to the tables in the backend.

Unfortunately, we are both working on the queries, which means we both need access to the frontend of the database. Is there a way split the db so we can both work on the queries, or where one of us could work on the reports and the other on the queries?

Comment: I don't think there is a concurrent development strategy for MS Access that does not involve copying stuff around.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247292/working-with-multiple-programmers-on-ms-access#250852 good tips in there

Comment: Actually, as the link shows, Visual Source Safe and source code control DOES in fact work with Access. So, in addition to a split, you can use source code control to allow multiple users to develop on the same application. Each user is permitted to check out individual objects such as forms, reports, SQL queries and code modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make 2 development copies of the front-end database.  Then each of you can work on your areas and not interfere.  That is how we do it on one of the databases that I manage.  Then when you are ready to place it in production, MS Access allows you to import queries, reports.